# faster string comparison for sorting, for unique()

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, unique

I have 4e7 `std::string`s, each about 3 to 30 characters long, with many duplicates.
I'm putting them in a `std::set`.

Calling `set::insert` for each string becomes intractably slow well before it would complete with about 1e7 unique strings.  So [instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12826449/2097284) I `push_back` each string into a `vector`, `sort()` and `unique()` that, and then [move](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20053022/2097284) the strings into a `set`.

It's still slow, but at least it finishes: 4 seconds to accumulate the vector, 30 more for `sort()`, 3 more for `unique()`.

The bottleneck is `sort()`.  **But I don't need the strings to be lexicographically sorted!**  I just need duplicate strings to be contiguous, for `unique()`.  Their order is irrelevant.
Is there a simpler, faster string comparison function for `sort()` that I could use instead of its default one?

Or should I build the set faster by iterating over the vector with a hash table on the side, to skip duplicates?  Or replace `set` with `hash_set` or `unordered_set`?

**Edit:** I'm building on Linux with g++ 4.8.4, with the only flags being `-std=c++11 -O3`.

Comment: I would definitely recommend you measure using `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: Relevant, possibly a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14023106/1896169

Comment: This blog (?) post has some discussion on the requested algorithm: https://lemire.me/blog/2008/05/01/i-am-seeking-an-efficient-algorithm-to-group-identical-values-in-an-array/

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune I see no mention how you built your application that you are testing.  Are you running an optimized build, or a "debug", non-optimized build?

Comment: An idea assuming comparing the strings is part of the problem: you could precompute the hashes of the strings and sort based on that hash. Within each region of equal hashes, you'd have to sort again due to possible hash collisions, but it's still possible that this could be faster.

Comment: If you just need to make the strings unique, I'd recommend using `std::unordered_set` (of a third-party library for hash sets, if you need additional performance. `std::unordered_set` is constrained in how performant it can be due to the requirements of it's interface)

Comment: The right data structure is unordered_set, and the duplicate link is not a perfect match, but it's saying you may also have issues with unnecessary temporaries while building your set. Because std::set has the same complexity as sorting the vector, if that shows a speed difference then you have issues with temporaries, and those will likely still be there in the unordered_set solution. But it's difficult for us to help there as you did not post the code.

Comment: If you know your strings are never going to be more than 30 chars long, you might try replacing `std::string` with e.g. `char[32]` or something equivalent to that.  Avoiding heap allocations could provide a significant speedup.

Answer (score 2):

@Someprogrammerdude, @J.AntonioPerez, @KennyOstrom: `std::unordered_set` is 6x faster. Post an answer and I'll accept it.  (This offer may have been lost in all those comments.)

```
vector<string> v;
loop { v.push_back(my_string[i]; }
```

Slow original:

```
sort(v.begin(), v.end());
v.erase(unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());
set<string> noduplicates = set<string>(
  make_move_iterator(v.begin()), make_move_iterator(v.end()));
```

6x faster than the preceding code block:

```
unordered_set<string> noduplicates =
  unordered_set<string>(
  make_move_iterator(v.begin()), make_move_iterator(v.end()));
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer. It's still a valid answer and you've gone through the effort of testing it.

Comment: 6x faster than sorted_set or 6x faster than sort+unique?

Comment: Than sort+erase+unique+move, i.e. the preceding code block.